# making title according to the image size how do i solve this issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image and an `h2` title that appears on top of image...

Here is a screenshot for your reference:

[image]

I want something like this

[image]

**CSS**:

```
h2 {
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #222;
  padding: 11px;
  top: 195px;
  opacity: .8;
  font-size: 13px;
  /* left: 349px; */
  text-align: left;
  /* bottom: -52px; */ 
  width: 100%;

.post img {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -32px;
}
```

I don't know that much about JS or jQuery: is there any method that will display only 2 or 3 words? I think that can resolve the issue. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you put your code on Fiddle

Comment: 1) you should include all the elements needed to answer in your question, this includes all HTML/CSS for the layout. and a fiddle makes answering much easier 2) try to write complete words, this is not a sms...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you don't need any JS to get what you need. Check out this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMYD7/

Example HTML structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="path_to_img" alt=""/>
    <div class="title">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit....
    </div>
</div>
```

No JavaScript here. Just try figuring out something similar, working with HTML and CSS. If JavaScript is not necessary, it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using in you `h2` css:

```
padding: 11px;
width: 100%;
```

consequently it will result width 100% + 11px (padding-left) + 11px (padding-right)

Just remove the `width: 100%` and it will work, because by default the h2 will fit 100%

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the solution is in css, and it is because of the padding being added on top of the 100%;

```
h2 {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Not sure of your exact case, but this may fix it.